# R fitdistr for Beta distribution: which starting parameters?

Tags: r, estimation, python, beta

I need to fit my data into a Beta distribution and retrieve the alpha parameter. I'm trying to use R from python (rpy2) and my code looks like:

```
from rpy2 import *
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
MASS = importr('MASS') #myVector is a Numpy array with values between 0 and 1
MASS.fitdistr(myVector,"beta")
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in function (x, densfun, start, ...)  : 
  'start' must be a named list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 82, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 34, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in function (x, densfun, start, ...)  : 
  'start' must be a named list
```

I can't seem to find any good documentation for R with detailed examples, so I only found [this](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Beta.html):

> ***start***   A named list giving the parameters to be optimized with initial values. This can be omitted for some of the named
>   distributions (see Details). ...  Additional parameters, either for
>   densfun or for optim. In particular, it can be used to specify bounds
>   via lower or upper or both. If arguments of densfun (or the density
>   function corresponding to a character-string specification) are
>   included they will be held fixed.

I really have no clue as to:

- what to put as a starting parameters and how that will affect my estimation
- what syntax to use in Python, since `start=list(shape1=0.5, shape2=0.5)` won't do the trick

Any hint?

Comment: At a minimum, you will want to read the `R` manual pages for [fitdistr](http://www.stat.ucl.ac.be/ISdidactique/Rhelp/library/MASS/html/fitdistr.html) and [the beta distribution](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prob/vignettes/charfunc.pdf).  Together, they reveal that the `R` command for what you're trying to do is something like `fitdistr(x, "beta", start=list(shape1=1/2, shape2=1/2))`.

Comment: Thanks. One big problem is that `fitdistr(x, "beta", start=list(shape1=1/2, shape2=1/2))` won't get accepted by Python's interpreter. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
`

Comment: I also couldn't find any examples of fitdistr with the start parameter in python.

Comment: The docs for rpy2 suggest you might want to use a `dict` object to pass lists as arguments.  If that doesn't work, create a [VECSXP object](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.1/html/rinterface.html#index-18).  At any rate, because this is purely a programming interface question, you will be better served on SO--I'll migrate this question for you.

Comment: Dictionaries didn't work, but I found a solution anyway.  I don't understand the output of `fitdistr`, though. I'm fitting my data into a Beta distribution and I want to get the estimated alpha parameter. The output of `fitdistr` is a list of four components: parameter estimates, estimated standard errors, estimated variance-covariance matrix, the log-likelihood. So I'm interested in 'parameters estimates', which contains 2 values. Which one is my alpha?  I couldn't find an explanation in the documentation.

Comment: See p. 2 of the second link in my first comment: `shape1` is alpha and `shape2` is beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after a little bit more of digging, I found a solution:

```
from rpy2.robjects import DataFrame
starter= DataFrame({'shape1':0.5,'shape2':0.5})
x = MASS.fitdistr(myValues, "beta", start=starter))
```